# Is turning space into time and time into space possible from an observer's perspective?

Tags: spacetime

If the distinction between space and time depends on the reference frame, what reference frame should we use to perceive time as space and space as time?

Comment: There is no such frame.

Comment: @CuriousOne What is the reason that there is no such frame?

Comment: Can you go backwards in time in three different ways? I can go backwards in space, in three different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you choose your $t$ and $x$ coordinates and you draw the usual spacetime diagram. Then on this diagram you plot the $t'$ and $x'$ axes for an observer moving at a sped $v$ relative to you. The results will look like:

[image: Spacetime diagram]

On your diagram the axes of the moving observer are rotated relative to your axes by an angle $\theta$ given by:

$$ \tan\theta = \frac{v}{c} $$

Since $v$ cannot exceed, or even reach, $c$ the fraction $v/c$ is always less than one so the angle $\theta$ is always less than $\pi/4$. That means there is no frame in which the time axis becomes the spatial axis or vice versa.